# JPA lazy loading and Generics

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, jpa, lazy-loading

I have a domain model with a few Generics in it that I try to put into JPA. My example is the domain of events where you have Events like Concerts and you have Tickets like ConcertTickets.

Event:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING, name="s_discriminator")
public abstract class Event {
...
}
```

Concert:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorValue("Concert")
public class Concert extends Event {
...
}
```

Ticket:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING, name="s_discriminator")
public abstract class Ticket<E extends Event> {

  ...

  @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Event.class)
  private E event;

  public E getEvent() {
    return event;
  }
}
```

ConcertTicket:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorValue("Concert")
public class ConcertTicket extends Ticket<Concert> {
    ...
}
```

Service:

```
ConcertTicket ticket = dao.findTicket(id);
Concert concert = ticket.getConcert();
```

This works. The targetEntity is necessary, otherwise I get following Error:

> Property Ticket.event has an unbound type and no explicit target entity. 
>   Resolve this Generic usage issue or set an explicit target attribute (eg 
>   @OneToMany(target=) or use an explicit @Type

Up to this point I had no trouble with my model. But I noticed that my performance didn't do well. The solution was to turn the relation between the ticket and the Event into Lazy Loading:

```
  @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Event.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  private E event;
```

Now the problems start. When I call the Service as posted above, I get following Exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: Event_$$_jvst610_48 cannot be cast to
>   Concert

At runtime, nothing is known about Generics. So when the JPA Implementation (Hibernate) creates an instance of "event", there is no information available that it's actually is a "Concert". Therefore a subclass of "Event" and not of "Concert" is created.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? I know there is 2 obvious solutions: a) avoid generics b) use eager loading. I'm hoping for a solution where I can keep both.

Comment: Don't use instanceof and casts. Use the visitor pattern.

Comment: solution c) : JPA providers that correctly support generics don't need targetEntity specifying. Similarly if these providers don't use "proxies" and instead use bytecode enhancement then they don't have that ClassCastException either.

Comment: I don't think the problem is big enough to swap out the JPA provider. I'm tempted though :-)

Comment: @JBNizet : I'm not using instanceof or casts. So I'm not sure how a visitor pattern would help me.

Comment: @EasterBunnyBugSmasher have you got any solution for this?

Comment: first solution was to make a slight modification to the Domain model so I could eagerly load those relations. Second solution was to get rid of the generics. Considering the complexity, the benefit just wasn't worth it. I got rid of a lot of complexity by adding a Switch Statement in one spot.

Comment: @EasterBunnyBugSmasher Didn't see your update, thanks though. Adding my answer how did I solve finally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue and annotating Superclass with @Proxy(lazy=false) did the trick. You can try the following, though not sure it will save your purpose.

```
@Proxy(lazy=false)
public abstract class Event {
 ...
}
```

Comment: interesting. But I no longer have the code to try it.

Comment: :-) np, may help others.

Comment: and then I suddenly had the same problem again. Tried your solution and it did the trick! ... and I was already worried about needing something complicated.

Comment: and now I notice the downside of this solution. My lazy-loaded relations to this entity were suddenly eager loaded. So I'll remove this again and come up with something better